# Переход между Activity (Android)

Tags: android, android-studio

На главном Activity размещается 8 кнопок, также есть 8 вспомогательных Activity, как сделать, чтобы, первая кнопка отправляла на первое Activity, вторая на второе и т.д.?
Пример, по которому я начал делать:

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

```
Button button;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(this);
   }
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.button:
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity_2.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Блин, неужели сложно вдумчиво посмотреть на пример и догадаться самому? Или найти другой пример. Ну это же самые основы, которые есть в любой книжке.

Answer (score 1):

Создание кнопок:

```
button_1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_1);
button_1.setOnClickListener(this);
button_2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_2);
button_2.setOnClickListener(this);
button_3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_3);
button_3.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Продолжать пока кнопки не кончатся.

В обработчик нажатий:

```
case R.id.button_1:
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity_1.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    break;
case R.id.button_2:
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity_2.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    break;
case R.id.button_3:
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity_3.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    break;
```